# Why does %u %d not work on UNIX/LINUX for printing addresses

Tags: c, linux, unix, pointers

I know that %d is for int, and %u for unsigned int and %p for the address.
But my question is we can print the address using %u,%d on a Windows machine but the same cannot be done on Linux.

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x=15;
    int *p;
    p=&x;

    printf("%d \n",x);
    printf("%d \n",&x);
    printf("%u \n",&x);
    printf("%p \n",p);
    printf("%x \n",p);
    printf("%u \n",&p);

return 0;   
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
15
2358812
2358812
000000000023FE1C
23fe1c
2358800
```

It is seen that the hex value(23fe1c) is changed to decimal using %d and %u.

But the exact same code gives error on Unix/Linux.

ERROR:

```
format (%d) expects arguments of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int*'
```

Comment: Giving mismatched data to `printf` leads to **undefined behavior**. Your compiler on Windows accidentally accepted it, but one on Linux didn't.

Comment: Note that `%p` is for printing `void*`, so you should convert the pointer before passing it to `printf` i.e. `printf("%p \n",(void*)p);`

Comment: To make it clear, you can't print a pointer value using `%d` because a pointer is not an integer.  And an integer is not a pointer.  Just because using `%d` to print a pointer works on some platforms doesn't mean it will work everywhere.  But it is wrong to treat a pointer as an integer - *anywhere*.  You'll learn that the hard way when you start doing 64-bit programming.

Answer (score 3):

GCC has the ability to perform type checking on variadic functions, specifically using the [`format` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes). This forces a check that the types passed as the variadic arguments exactly match the format string supplied.

Answer (score 2):

GCC complains because the data types used in the *printf* format string and the passed parameters are not compatible. The portable and standard way to print a pointer is by using the **%p** specifier. However, you can find other places where people may use %x for the same purpose. As others have said, using %u and %d are not compatible with a pointer data type. They may work on some compilers like in the Windows case but other stricter compiler (like GCC in this case) could complain about the datatype being passed since **int** is not the same as **int***. In order to use the **%p** notation you have to cast the pointer to void, as from the C99 standard:

> p The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

That's said, the %p is implementation defined so the output could change from an implementation to the other. Any way using %d or %u to print a pointer in general is not a good idea. Depending on the implementation a pointer could be a simple int or a long int. So you could get an undefined behavior if you try to print a pointer by using a %d or %u on a machine where the addresses are stored in long int variables.

If you would like to control the output then another option is to use `uintptr_t` provided by `#include <inttypes.h>`.

Comment: "*Depending on the implementation a pointer could be a simple int or a long int.*" it could even be *two* integers.

Comment: You mean the case e.g of a 64bit machine where a compiler is using 4bytes integers?

Comment: No, I am referring to segmented addresses like: `0xabcd:0x1234` (further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation)

Comment: Actually `%p` gained traction when (a) 64-bit addresses became common and (b) much *later* gcc added a warning to point this out as a problem.  Segmented addresses would be nice to warn about, but 20 years overdue demonstrates that they were not a factor for gcc's warning.